# Connecting to a Windows Network drive via SMB

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, smb

I'm a relative `linux-noob` still. I've managed to join my machine to my company's domain however I'm for some reason unable to access any of our file shares through the "connect to server" function on Nautilus.

Its asking me for a user-name, domain and password.

I believe I'm entering the correct details but I'm being refused? Is there something I'm missing or I could be doing wrong?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, it might be something simple as I'm used to the windows methods of things.

Running on 18.10 Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried mounting in command window?
Something like

```
mount -t cifs //myserver/share /local/path -o user=USERNAME,pass=PASSWORD,domain=DOMAINNAME
```

It should not be important if your host is joined to the domain. Or do you want to auth with kerberos or something like that?

Comment: Thanks i tried this but im getting "mount: /home/it/Documents: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program." error, any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed package cifs-utils? Is there a command called "mount.cifs"?

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the help, this worked!